# words a speaker says in the video?

Tags: word-usage, usage, active-vs-passive

I cannot make out what the speaker said in this [video](https://youtu.be/Y3KtElTUObc). It is at the [9 minute 44 second point](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3KtElTUObc&feature=youtu.be&t=584). It sounds like he said *chores up*, but that doesn't make any sense. Here is the context:

> It is difficult to accrue muscle mass, unless you are very overweight and undertrained, but that **chores up** in a few weeks.

From the context it is clear that if someone is overweight and indertrained it is possible to gain muscle and shed fat, but that halts with time.

Comment: I think he means to say "shores up" — he garbles it a little, while swallowing.  Still, I'm not quite sure what the intransitive meaning of "shores up" would be in the context of "net calories in/calories out" and the inability to put on muscle mass while dieting to restrict calorie intake.  Perhaps "becomes steadier" or "evens out".  To shore something up (transitive) means to reinforce it physically to prevent it from falling over or collapsing.  It's a kind of "middle voice" construction here, I think.

Comment: I can hear this one: "but that sure is upon a few weeks"

Comment: Does "upon" mean "after" there?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with "the commenter who spells his name with upside-down letters thereby making it needlessly difficult for others to refer to him"; I think the video guy is saying "shores up", being a spur-of-the-moment, and not particularly idiomatic way of saying that the effect in question goes away or evens out (as said upside-down-lettered guy says).

As to the intended *meaning*, I think it's what you, Dmytro, said, but more precisely. I think the point is that for people who are sufficiently overweight (i.e. fat) and sufficiently under-trained, and only for such people, there is a limited window of time at the start of a new regime where they can *reliably and predictably* both lose fat and gain muscle. However, quite quickly -- presumably as their body begins to react and attempts to regain homeostasis in various control systems -- it reaches the point where the precise extent of loss of fat versus gain of muscle is very much harder to control.

In other words, once you've reached and passed that "honeymoon" stage, you might find periods of time where you can push all the weights you want, and find that you achieve nothing but fat loss -- the usual ecto/hard-gainer problem.